# I can't see how was done this substitution from varialble $x$ to $y$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, integration

How is done this substitution from x to y?

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx = n^{n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{n(lny-y)}dy $$

it is in a derivation of Stirling's Approximation from a book of statistical mechanics.

Comment: The substitution is $y = x/n$, and you use the fact that $x^n = e^{n \ln(x)}$.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the Math Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $y=\frac xn$ such that you get

$$\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}\text{d}x = n\int_0^\infty (yn)^ne^{-ny}\text{d}y =n^{n+1}\int_0^\infty \text{d}y e^{n(\log y - y)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.